# How to preserve special symbols when reading in a file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, special-characters

I am trying to read in a file that has special symbols like:
- l"Université
- Borély

But Java is outputting things like: 
- l"universit√©
- Borely

Is there a way to read in a file that would preserve any special symbols? What format should the file be?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you specifying any type of encoding when you are reading the file? Try using UTF-16 and see if that works. BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-16"));

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Read [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html). Describe the input and output mechanisms. What device are you writing to?

Comment: I am reading the file using a Scanner object, and I am writing it out to a file using PrintWriter.

Comment: this seems to work, but only for subset of characters. For example, if my input is:

Wólka_Siemieńska, 
Siemień, 
Pozo_Cañada, 
l"université, 
Moskenesøya

I get:
Wólka_Siemie?ska, 
Siemie?, 
Pozo_Cañada, 
l"université, 
Moskenesøya

Comment: Ensure the read and write operations are reciprocal: they use the same character set arguments; the character set is the correct one for the data source. Without code, it isn't possible to point out the error.

Answer (score 2):

All should be well if you use UTF-8 encoding when you write and read the file.

Comment: That is what I am using right now, but it seems like all the special characters are messed up!

Comment: You didn't do it properly, then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for the Latin1 ISO. Try something like that:

```
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                   new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1"));
```